# How to hook a transformer to a outlet

Tags: ac-dc

I bought some plug ends to hook up to my outlet
[image]

I wanted to connect the plug with some wires, I was told that I needed these type of wires [image]

I however wanted to use low voltage wires like these [image]

It will be hooked up to a transformer that will output 6 volts, and then connected to a rectifier if I were to use the low voltage wires instead of the thick ones would that cause any issues? I believe that the amount of power that enters the system is the same as it leaves so I believe that the low voltage wires shouldn't cause issues as long as its under 1 Amp

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, but you are asking your readers to follow three links to Amazon advert pages just to understand your question. Post photos in your question to make it easy for your readers and so that the question makes sense when the Amazon links die.

Comment: What is the *actual* voltage rating of the "low-voltage" wire? Remember that regardless of the transformer outputting 6 V, the voltage on the wires between the plug and transformer will be 120 Vrms and as such, your wiring must be rated to withstand that level of voltage.

Comment: Whatever happened to just hooking up a transformer to the entrance panel screw-strips with vise-grips? All this plugs and wires stuff is confusing... Or did that gene pool disappear for some reason? (It's Sunday and I'm looking forward to another week of classes with students who probably couldn't eat except that someone else already plugged in the toaster for them. So I'm in a mood of sorts. My apologies.) To the OP: *Use appropriate mains wire for the primary! Low current fine. Feel free to use appropriate low-voltage wire for the secondary. Your plugs are 15 A rated, so no worries there.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to DIY.SE

Comment: the problem with using low voltage wire for 120 V is that the insulation may not be sufficient to prevent arcing between the conductors or to prevent leakage current from flowing into your hands when you touch the wire

Comment: you should not use those plugs for extra low voltafge (like 6V)  especially if you are in USA or some other country that uses those plugs for regular appliances.  if someone accidnetally plus one of them into 120V  bad stuff will happen.  for 6V XT30 plugs might be a better choice,

Comment: You REALLY need to clarify the question. Those are mains rated plugs which should be used with the mains rated cable shown. If you want to use these plugs at 6V ... DON'T! Find different plugs which CANNOT be inserted into mains outlets and destroy your 6V systems. If you meant to use these for the 6V transformer INPUT - use the right cable. Then you can use the LV cable on the transformer OUTPUT : that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the input, you need wire that is rated for the 120-volt plugs. The power level does not make much difference, you need the proper wire for the voltage and you should connect the ground wire to the frame of the transformer. I believe that you can buy the proper wire by the foot at Home Depot or buy an extension cord and cut off the receptacle end. The low voltage wire is good for the secondary.